# restart policy in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to create a deployment on Kubernetes and using restart policy on failure ?
I did a small research but didn't find anything that enables restart policy on failure for Deployment.

KR

Answer (score 1):

`restartPolicy` for `kind: Deployment` [support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template) `Always` only.

> One of the requirements is "restart policy on failure max 3 times"

Try:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  template:
    backoffLimit: 3  # <-- max fail 3 times
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure  # <-- You can do this with job
      containers:
      - name: busybox
        image: busybox
        command: ["ash","-c","sleep 15"]  # <-- replace with an invalid command to see backoffLimit in action
```

Comment: Any other ways to add restart policy? maybe create a job or something else and link it to deployment?

Comment: why do you need any other way ?

Comment: You don't need `OnFailure`, pod under Deployment always restart even it has completed.

Comment: One of the requirements is "restart policy on failure max 3 times"

Comment: Try the updated answer.